# String field which need to be pass as an integer in URL in Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

There is different case to develop  an API in asp.net for me. Could you please help me to figure it out?

There is "string" field in database that is need to be passed in Url for "Get" but it need to be pass as an integer. There is a condition for that as well which is : The value in this field is padded with leading zeroes to make up 8 digits. e.g. EntityId 20 would have a value of 00000020.

Database looks like:[image]

the idea that I come up so far , creating private member for "Entity" in the model file to store the string one and create the "int" for "EntityId" in there. But not sure how good is this approach? and if it is good , do not know how to implement that.

Thanks

Comment: You can append zeros in front of the input number and make it 8 character long and then use it to query in EF

Comment: converting a varchar type from database to integer is not safe. You should consider changing the types.

Comment: I am not allowed to change the data type in DB. it is part of requirement

Comment: This design is a recipe for disaster. What's stopping you from accidentally using "Banana" as your entity id? (or someone "evil" that gained access to your DB, for that matter)? If the value is suppose to be an integer, use an integer data type to store it. You can always add leading zeros when you want to display it in your UI - but using a string to store a number just for the sake of leading zeros is plat out wrong.